# ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ERROR with Express Middleware

Tags: node.js, express, path, response, webstorm

This seems to be a common error with file paths but my problem is a but more strange because code worked fine yesterday but not today (and I did not change any code). My folder directory is quite simple:

```
-node_modules
-public
    -css
    -js
    control_panel.html
    index.html
app.js
packages.json
```

[image]

and I am using an Express middleware inside app.js to help render files.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function get(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');
});

app.get('/control_panel', function get(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/control_panel.html');
});
```

When I try to open index.html in the browser, there is no problem, everything works as expected. When I try to open control_panel.html in the browser, however, I get `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/control_panel.html' at Error (native)`

What is causing the problem?

Comment: `res.sendFile('/control_panel.html')` will not work.  The `control_panel.html` file is not located at the path `'/control_panel.html'`.  Plus, you should be using `express.static('public')` for those routes anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00  When I specify `app.use(express.static("public"));`, doesn't the app start looking for files under the folder "public". In this case, control_panel.html is under public

Comment: Not for `res.sendFile()`.  `express.static()` only works for incoming requests.  `res.sendFile()` needs a real, working path to the file.

Comment: @jfriend00 is there an alternative to using res.sendFile() for html files?

Comment: Alternative for what purpose?  A static file should be served with `express.static()` and there's no reason to make a manually created route for a static file.

Comment: @jfriend00 so basically I should not use `app.get` at all for static files?

Comment: Correct.  You should place all static files in their own directory hierarchy and you should organize them and the way you reference them from HTML pages such that `express.static()` can serve them automatically.  No reason to create routes for them.  And, don't put any of non-public files like `app.js` in that directory hierarchy either because you don't want them getting served automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number of relevant points based on your situation:

1. All static assets (html files, images, CSS files, client-side script files, etc...) should be serviced automatically with an appropriate `express.static(...)` statement.  You should not be creating individual routes for static resources.
2. To make `express.static()` work properly, you must locate all your static resources in a directory hierarchy that contains only files meant to be public.
3. Your private server-side files such as `app.js` should not be in that public directory hierarchy.  They should be elsewhere.
4. Your path to `express.static()` is not correct.
5. Your path for `res.sendFile()` is not correct.

What I would suggest you do to fix things is the following:

1. Move app.js out of the `public` directory.  It needs to be in a private directory.  I'd suggest the `public` directory be a sub-directory from where app.js is located.
2. Then, your `express.static()` in `app.js` will work property to serve your static HTML fiels.
3. Then, you can remove the two routes you have for `index.html` and `control_panel.html` because `express.static()` should be serving them.

Here's one hierarchy that would work:

```
server
    app.js
    public
        index.html
        control_panel.html
```

And, an app.js like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// serve static files found in the public sub-directory automatically
app.use(express.static("public")); 

app.listen(80);
```

Comment: One thing to note is currently, app.js is actually outside of the public folder, as seen in that picture in the question. Maybe that picture is confusing

Comment: @b11 - Yes, the picture is very confusing.

Comment: sorry it's a screenshot of webstorm