# Node.js - How do I export Excel files to client/UI which are already available in a folder?

Tags: node.js, excel, directory, export-to-excel, excel4node

I have a folder which contains all my Excel Sheets which are built using  the npm package [excel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node).

Now I want to export these files to users dependent on the name of files.

How do I do that?

I've tried referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/how-do-you-get-a-list-of-the-names-of-all-files-present-in-a-directory-in-node-j) although I don't understand how to export those files to the user.

Comment: what do you mean by users, do you want to send it to the client?

Comment: Yes, I want to send it to the Client

Comment: ok , Please post some code you have tried to send them to client.

Comment: I have tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727191/7854532). However, it is only able to list all files in console or on the browser. I want to list all excel sheets to my Clients so that they can directly download them. I want to do something like [Bootstrap Listr](https://idleberg.com/demo/Bootstrap-Listr-2/), but in either plain html5 or in node.js

Comment: did you try this answer as well? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25580289/7889129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got your question right, you want to send an excel file when a client makes an API call with possibly a username.
To do so here is some pseudo code :

```
app.get('/user/:username', function(req, res) {
  const username = req.params['username'];
  const filePath =  "/path/to/"+username+".excel" 

  // Check if file specified by the filePath exists 
  fs.exists(filePath, function(exists){
       if (exists) {     
         //send the file to client
         res.sendFile(filePath);
       }
    });
})
```

> note* [res.sendFile()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) is supported by Express v4.8.0 onwards.

---

Now as per your comments if you want to send a list of all files to the client you will have to return an array of strings and render it on the UI.

```
app.get('/user/all', function(req, res) {

  const testFolder =  "/path/to/folder";

  // read the folder and set the result in a variable    
  var listOfFiles = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);
  // send a JSON or any other response with these strings
  res.json({"allFiles" : listOfFiles});
})
```

Comment: @damjit07 , thank you for the revert. Your answer is working perfectly when coupled with my app. However, it is working only in `server.js` file. When I try to use the same code in other file and use router to route the incoming request to that file, then it gives me [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39492259/enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat-error-with-express-middleware)

Comment: I guess the issue will be with the relative path of your folder and code file

Comment: Yes. Its a path issue. Anyways, thank you for the answer.